# Create JsonArray from List

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

I'd need to create a **javax.json.JsonArray** object (Java EE 7 API) from a java.util.List of JsonObjects.
Formerly, when using JSON API I used to do it simply with:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(list);
```

But I can see there's no equivalent constructor in javax.json.JsonArray.
Is there a simple way (other than browsing across all the List) to do it ? 
Thanks

Comment: The javadoc contains examples...

Comment: What is `list` in this example?

Comment: Already checked. But Javadocs contains the following example:JsonArray value = Json.createArrayBuilder()
     .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
         .add("type", "home")
         .add("number", "212 555-1234"))
     .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
         .add("type", "fax")
         .add("number", "646 555-4567"))
     .build(); This is not what I have asked- I already have a List<JsonObjects>

Comment: i didn't know there was a json package within Java.

Comment: @Sikorski in Java EE only

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately the standard JsonArrayBuilder does not take a list as input. So you will need to iterate over the list.

I don't know how your List looks but you could make a function like:

```
public JsonArray createJsonArrayFromList(List<Person> list) {
    JsonArray jsonArray = Json.createArrayBuilder();
    for(Person person : list) {
        jsonArray.add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("firstname", person.getFirstName())
            .add("lastname", person.getLastName()));
    }
    jsonArray.build();
    return jsonArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems that's the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is interessted in how to do this with Java 8 Streams. The same code snippet:

```
public JsonArray createJsonArrayFromList(List<Person> list) {
    JsonArray jsonArray = Json.createArrayBuilder();
    list.stream().forEach(person -> jsonArray.add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("firstname", person.getFirstName())
            .add("lastname", person.getLastName())));
    jsonArray.build();
    return jsonArray;
}
```